# Blank userform field results in in Mismatch Error when using CDate()

Tags: excel, vba

I have almost no clue about VBA but was assigned to fix an error, so please allow this very basic question:

As far as I can tell the error results from writing a blank userform cell to a worksheet. The value has to be in date format, so `CDate()` is used but this results in

> Run Time Error 13 - Type Mismatch/Blank

when the field is blank.

How can I fix this?

```
Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 128).Value = CDate(TextBox128.Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Test for a date explicitly:

```
If Isdate(TextBox128.Text) then Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 128).Value = CDate(TextBox128.Text)
```